# PHP form validation and .srt MIME type?

Tags: php, validation, mime-types, srt

I have a small PHP script that fixes some errors in Subtitle Workshop .srt-files. It works fine, but i have a problem validating .srt-files MIME types. Here's a part of the code in question:

```
if ( $_FILES['file']['type'] != 'text/plain' &&
$_FILES['file']['type'] != 'application/x-subrip') {    
$error .= '<p>MIME type is not allowed!</p>';
}
```

.srt-files are actually plain text files. When i upload subtitles in .txt-file my script works fine. But when i try to upload the same file with .srt extension i get "MIME type is not allowed!" error. 'application/x-subrip' (found it [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)) is obviously a culprit. But what should i use instead? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you could do this validation. Plain text file may have a lot of mimetypes, like "text/plain", "application/octet-stream", "text/str", etc.
You could do a white list, but also need to do another type of validation, maybe by content, or using a library.

Comment: Thanks! I already have some other type of validations as well (file size and extensions). I removed MIME type validation now and replaced it with the validation based on file content (using some regex).